# how to add multiple number of same XML tags when XML parsing in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am parsing a XML file and my XML looks like:

```
<List>
<CompanyallProvidersList>
    <CityDetails>
           <City>NewYork</City>
            <Id>1</Id>
    </CityDetails>
    <StateDetails>
            <State>Alabaster</State>
      </StateDetails>
    <CityDetails>
             <City>Newyork</City>
              <Id>1</Id>
    </CityDetails>
 <StateDetails>
               <State>California</State>
       </StateDetails>
 </CompanyallProvidersList>
</List>
```

My parser code is like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {


if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CompanyallProvidersList"])
{
arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
srr=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
} 


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
[srr appendString:string];
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString    *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"City"])
{

[drr setObject:srr forKey:@"City"];
[srr release],srr=nil;
return;
} 

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Id"])
{

[drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Id"];
[srr release],srr=nil;
return; 
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"State"])
{

[drr setObject:srr forKey:@"State"];
[srr release],srr=nil;
return;
}


if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CompanyallProvidersList"])
{
[arr addObject:drr];
[drr release],drr=nil;
}
[srr release],srr=nil;

}
```

My output is like this:

```
NewYork
1
California
```

But I want the output to be :

```
 NewYork
 1
 Alabaster

NewYork
1
California
```

`I couldn't get it..Where Am I going wrong?

Any help would be appreciated......

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code probem is you are adding two values for same keys. So Second value replace the First value.
You need to add the following code toyour `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString    *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName` delegate

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"StateDetails"])
{
  [arr addObject:drr];
}
```

And change :

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CompanyallProvidersList"])
{
[drr release];
}
```

Also add the following code to your `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CityDetails"])
{
   drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

It'll work !!!

Now the code will look like:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{    
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CompanyallProvidersList"])
  {
     arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CityDetails"])
  {
     drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  srr=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString    *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"City"])
  {
    [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"City"];
    [srr release],srr=nil;
    return;
  } 

  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Id"])
  {

    [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Id"];
    [srr release],srr=nil;
    return; 
  }

  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"State"])
  {
    [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"State"];
    [srr release],srr=nil;
    return;
  }

   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"StateDetails"])
   {
     [arr addObject:drr];
   }

  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"CompanyallProvidersList"])
  {
     [drr release],drr=nil;
  }
  [srr release],srr=nil;
}
```

Comment: @Mithun .I have a small question I am getting like this:({ City="NewYork"; Id="1"; State=Alabaster;} { City="NewYork";Id="1";State=California}) How Can I remove all those ({"; from the response and display in a TableView with 2 rows?

Comment: @cutiepie: tell me. I think this output is from NSLog, is it ?

Comment: @cutiepieL if you want to take the data from a dictionary use `objectForKey` Like `NSMutableDictioanary *dict = [arr  objectAtIndex0];[NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"ID"]);`

Comment: Yes .U r right...It is from NSLog ..I want it in a tableView with 2 rows and a separator in between a row ..

Comment: @cutiepie: did you checked my above comment ?